# Using triple integrals to find mass of solid bounded by a sphere with radius 5 in the 1st octant with density function $p(x,y,z)=z$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, volume, upper-lower-bounds

This is easy enough to draw, it is just a wedge and 1/8 of a sphere centered at the origin. The mass will be given by: $$m= \int \int \int p(x,y,z)dV$$
I just need to figure out the bounds of the sphere, but that is where I get confused.

- Which coordinate system could/will work? Could I use rect, cyl, or spherical?
- Could I first figure it out in rectangular and then transform it any of the other systems? I haven't learned transformations yet.

If I use spherical, will my bounds be as follows? $$0 \le p \le5 \;\;\;\;
0 \le \theta \le {\pi\over2} \;\;\;\; 0 \le\phi \le{\pi \over 2}$$ and thus:
$$\int_0^{\pi \over 2} \int_0^{\pi \over 2} \int_0^5{(z)}p^2\sin\phi dp d \theta d \phi$$?

Thanks for any help, I have a hard time getting these problems figured out.

EDIT: I just noticed that z will need to be converted, but I'm still concerned about the bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using spherical coordinates $$\int_0^{\pi \over 2} \int_0^{\pi \over 2} \int_0^5{(z)}p^2\sin\phi dp d \theta d \phi$$

Thus  you need to substitute $pcos (\phi)$ for z in your
integrand.

The new integral is $$\int_0^{\pi \over 2} \int_0^{\pi \over 2} \int_0^5 p^3 \cos(\phi)\sin\phi dp d \theta d \phi$$

Comment: @MohammadRiaziKermani Yeah, I missed that at first but I made an edit above mentioning that. My main concern is that my bounds are correct and I can't see a reason why they aren't. Are you able to confirm they are correct? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your bounds are correct.